# TypeORM find all items if the condition returns false

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I updated an advert status to "in-renting" if today's date is between one of MANY possible rent requests

... - {from, currentDate, to} - {from, to} ...

```
async rentAllPossibleCar(): Promise<AdvertEntity[]> {
    const adverts = await this.advertsRepository.find({
      where: {
        advertStatus: AdvertStatus.ACTIVE,
        rentRequests: {
          status: RentRequestStatus.APPROVED,
          from: LessThan(new Date()),
          to: MoreThan(new Date()),
        },
      },
    });

    adverts.forEach((advert) => {
      advert.advertStatus = AdvertStatus.IN_RENTING;
    });
    await this.advertsRepository.save(adverts);

    return adverts;
  }
```

But if current day in NOT between rent requests period I must return an advert status back to Active. I don't know how to create this query.

... - {from, to} - currentDate - {from, to} - ...

[NestJs, TypeOrm, Typescript, Postresql]

Something like that (added Not) but it DOESN'T work with query

```
async activateAllRentingCar(): Promise<AdvertEntity[]> {
    const adverts = await this.advertsRepository.find({
      where: {
        advertStatus: AdvertStatus.IN_RENTING,
        rentRequests: Not({
          status: RentRequestStatus.APPROVED,
          from: LessThan(new Date()),
          to: MoreThan(new Date()),
        }),
      },
    });

    console.log(adverts);
    // advert.advertStatus = AdvertStatus.IN_RENTING;
    // await this.advertsRepository.save(advert);

    return adverts;
  }
```

Help me please

Answer (score 0):

```
const currentDate = new Date();
const adverts = await this.advertsRepository.createQueryBuilder('advert')
  .leftJoin('advert.rentRequests', 'rentRequest')
  .where('advert.advertStatus = :advertStatus', {advertStatus: AdvertStatus.IN_RENTING})
  .andWhere('rentRequest.status != :rentRequestStatus', {rentRequestStatus: RentRequestStatus.APPROVED})
  .andWhere(':currentDate NOT BETWEEN rentRequest.from AND rentRequest.to', { currentDate })
  .getMany();

//Update advert status to "Active" for those where current date is not between rent request dates
for (const advert of adverts) {
  const isActive = advert.rentRequests.every(rentRequest => {
    const fromDate = new Date(rentRequest.from);
    const toDate = new Date(rentRequest.to);
    return currentDate < fromDate || currentDate > toDate;
  });
  if (isActive) {
    advert.advertStatus = AdvertStatus.ACTIVE;
    await this.advertsRepository.save(advert);
  }
}
```

You should try using query builder for complex queries and typeorm's inbuilt methods not always be the solution you want.
In the code, we use left join to also retrieve rent requests associated with each advertisement.
After retrieving the advertisements, we iterate through them and check if the current date is not between the rent request dates for all the associated rent requests. If it is not, we set the advertStatus to "Active" and save the advertisement back to the database.